# how to make bat file python for task scheduler

Tags: python, jupyter, scheduler

I have a code in a python jupyter notebook and i need to run this every month with task scheduler,but i have a problem when im trying to make bat.file.
i write this code **jupyter nbconvert --to notebook --execute sawit.ipynb** in command prompt and the result came out error like in the photo.
Before this i'm trying alternative ways like add arguments and start in,but when im trying to run that task its always show command prompt but didnt do anything so im trying another ways which is make a python script to bat file.Thank you in advance!

[image: error]

Comment: Does it have to be a bat file? I meant I usually do .ps1

Comment: sorry,may i know what is ps1?

Comment: It is a powershell script. So what I will do is to convert your .pynb to .py. Then I create a file called whatever.ps1 with notepad. Inside the ps1, I will just run ```cd path-to-your-python-file```and the next line will be ```python .\yourfilename.py```. Put them in task scheduler: powershell.exe as the program and the .ps1 as the file to run